# Can i use daterange column and work with EF for PostgreSQL ,c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

Generally i have report data for some date range and i want to insert new, and delete old one for the same period.

I want to use column of type daterange in postgresql db.
I am using newest version of EF for postgre.
I want to be able to map my field to some property.
I want to be able select, remove and insert new based on this column.

I tried to map my context to :
public NpgsqlRange month_year { get; set; }
but got exception: “column "month_year" is of type daterange but expression is of type tsrange” – I understand that it is happening because the mapping works that way: NpgsqlRange => tsrange

I tried to use:
NpgsqlRange
but got next exception:
The property 'DBTable1.DateRangeNoda' is of type 'NpgsqlRange' which is not supported by current database provider – but shouldn’t this be already working ?
So my question is: Is there way to work in .net core using EF with column of type daterange?How?

```
using (var context = new postgresContext())
{ 
    var d = new DBTable1(){Text = "aaa" };
    d.DateRange1 = new NpgsqlRange<DateTime>(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today);

    //d.DateRangeNoda = new NpgsqlRange<LocalDate> 
    //                       (LocalDate.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today), 
    //                        LocalDate.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today) );
    //efNpgsqlDate>  not supported by provider

     context.dbTable1.Add(d); 

     context.SaveChanges();
}

public partial class DBTable1 
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public NpgsqlRange<DateTime> DateRange0 { get; set; }

    public NpgsqlRange<LocalDate> DateRangeNoda { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<DBTable1>(entity =>
    {
    entity.ToTable("test1");

    entity.Property(e => e.DateRange1).HasColumnName("daterange1"); 

    entity.Property(e => e.DateRangeNoda).HasColumnName("daterange"); 

    }); 
}
```

For now i end up using date column with FirstOfTheRange date :(

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a bit of confusion in your code sample above - you are accessing  property `DateRange1` whereas the DBTable1 class seems to contain `DateRange0`.

Npgsql supports two ways of interacting with date/time types: the built-in BCL types (e.g. DateTime) and [the NodaTime library](http://nodatime.org/). The built-in DateTime type is supported, but is mapped by default to PostgreSQL `timestamp` rather than `date`, since it has a time components. Therefore, a property of type `NpgsqlRange<DateTime>` will cause Npgsql to create a `tsrange` column (range of timestamp), rather than a `daterange`). It's possible to explicitly specify `daterange` as the column type, but you will encounter some subtle problems with this ([see this comment](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/493#issuecomment-401256028)).

If using NodaTime is OK, then things should work better, since NodaTime has a date-only type - `LocalDate` - so `NpgsqlRange<LocalDate>` automatically maps to `daterange`. To do this you will need to use the NodaTime plugin, [as specified in the docs](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nodatime.html).

Here's a full code sample for using a date range with NodaTime, including insertion and query:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new BlogContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

            ctx.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Duration = new NpgsqlRange<LocalDate>(new LocalDate(2011, 1, 1), new LocalDate(2011, 1, 3)) });
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            var x = ctx.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Duration.Contains(new LocalDate(2011, 1, 2)));
        }
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("<connection string>", o => o.UseNodaTime());

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NpgsqlRange<LocalDate> Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. My problem was using wrong package for Nodatime:<!--Wrong one <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.NodaTime" Version="4.0.5" />   -->
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.0" />
   <!--Good one --> <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime" Version="2.2.0" />

Answer (score 0):

Problem was using wrong package for NodaTime:

```
<!--Wrong one <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.NodaTime" Version="4.0.5" /> --> <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.0" /> 
<!--Good one --> 
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime" Version="2.2.0" />
```